# Git ignore won't work, but eclipse ignore works?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-kepler

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse. I used the Git GUI tool to place it under source control. 
Then, suddenly my project icons were decorated with git related images. Anyway, after that 
I wanted to keep the content of the images folder (inside WebContetnt folder) out of source control. 
So, I went into my project folder and modified the `.gitignore` file adding `/WebContent/img/*`. 
This does not change anything in eclipse.

So, I used an alternate approach. Project > Team > Git > Ignore. This works and the question 
mark image on the img folder icon vanishes.

I am not able to understand why my manual change does not work and also how eclipse suddenly
put it into source control. Please help me to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: After you changed manually, did you refresh the project in Eclipse (select the Project in the Project Navigator and press F5). The EGit plugin picks up manual changes for me, but if I don't hit F5 it just cannot know something changed.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore contents of the folder you have to have a folder name + forward slash and no asterisk: `WebContent/img/`

And, as @janos noted, don't forget to refresh your project/repository after manual change of your .gitignore file

Comment: I tried your answer. It does not work. I still see image folder with images listed under git.

Comment: most up-to-date info can be found using: 'git help gitignore'